# Postview Image API on Sony a5000

Tags: sony, sony-camera-api

The supported API grid indicated that the a5000 should have post view image size functions, but the APIs are not available when I call getAvailableAPIList. I am careful to initialize with startRecMode, and am sure that the camera function is set to "remote shooting." Other expected APIs are there such as actTakePicture, but not getPostviewImageSize, setPostviewImageSize, getSupportedPostviewImageSize, or getAvailablePostviewImageSize.

I have verified that my camera has the latest firmware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today Sony restores distribution of Camera Remote App. It is not firmware of camera. Try to update Camera Remote App. You can do it from camera menu. Before it you should connect camera to Wi-Fi.

Comment: I did the update to the Camera Remote App on the camera itself, and the APIs are now available! Thanks again.